# Geometric progression summation problem

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, geometric-progressions

> $n$ number of terms of a series are in geometric progression and their
>   common ratio is $r$. Summation of the first $m$ terms gives $S_m$. Then prove
>   that summation of products of two consecutive numbers in that series
>   is $$\frac{r}{r+1} S_m S_{m-1} $$ when $n=2m$?

Comment: You should start by looking up the definition of a geometric progression, what a common ratio is in that context and then tackle the problem.

Comment: @Partha Sarathi Das Please check your statement carefully. What "when $n=2m$?" mean? what is $n$.

Comment: I am sorry n=N it's a typo.

Answer (score 2):

Let $(cr^n)_{n\geq 0}$ be a non-constant geometric progression then 
$$S_m=\sum_{n=0}^{m-1}cr^n=c\frac{1-r^{m}}{1-r}.$$
Now note that the "summation of products of two consecutive numbers in that series" is given by
$$\sum_{n=0}^{m-1}(cr^n)(cr^{n+1})=c^2r\sum_{n=0}^{m-1}(r^2)^{n}=c^2r\frac{1-r^{2m}}{1-r^2}=\frac{r}{r+1}S_{1}S_{2m}.$$
Something is wrong in your statement.

Comment: I already did upto this and extracted Sm but What did to find Sm-1 is Sm - cr^(m-1) it is not fitting into the simplified summation of product of two consecutive numbers. @Robert Z

Comment: @Partha Sarathi Das Yes, I think that something is wrong in the statement. See my edited answer. Where does this exercise come from?

Answer (score 0):

The original geometric progression for $n=2m$ is: 
$$a,ar,ar^2,...,ar^{2m-2},ar^{2m-1}.$$
The sum of $m$ and $m-1$ terms:
$$S_m=\frac{a(r^m-1)}{r-1}; S_{m-1}=\frac{a(r^{m-1}-1)}{r-1}.$$

The geometric progression formed by products of consecutive terms (overall $m$ terms) is: 
$$a^2r,a^2r^3,...,a^2r^{4m-3}.$$
The sum of $m$ terms:
$$S_m^*=\frac{a^2r((r^2)^m-1)}{r^2-1}=\frac{r}{r+1}\cdot \frac{a(r^m-1)}{r-1}\cdot a(r^m+1)=\frac{r}{r+1}\cdot S_m\cdot a(r^m+1).$$

Comment: yes I had the same result as yours just wanted to be sure. It's problem from book namely Rudiments of Mathematics